# Psalm 23:4 syllable division: how does the original Hebrew come to 11 syllables?

Tags: the-bible, hebrew-language, robert-alter

In Robert Alter's *The Book of Psalms: A Translation with Commentary* (2009), the author examines the first line of Psalm 23:4 in the Hebrew and arrives at eight words (so far so good) and eleven syllables. Here is the relevant excerpt from [page xxx](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Book_of_Psalms_A_Translation_with_Co/2iYEhR1Dz8YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PR20):

> The initial line—there are two in the verse—of Psalm 23:4 grandly reads in the 1611 translation: "Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil." This beautiful line has understandably moved readers for four centuries, but it is the stately beauty of a leisurely prose amble, not of a line of poetry (or, if one prefers, the beauty of a proto-Whitmanesque line of poetry rather than of biblical poetry). **The Hebrew sounds like this: *gam ki-ʾelekh begeyʾ tsalmawet / loʾ-ʾiyraʾ raʿ*. If we ignore the Masoretic hyphenation, the Hebrew comes to eight words, eleven syllables.** The King James Version weighs in with seventeen words, twenty syllables.

Alter's division of this verse as it pertains to syllable division is where I get a little lost. I couldn't arrive at the same number (11 syllables) he did and was curious if someone could enlighten me regarding his analysis of this verse.

Answer (score 6):

כִּֽי־אֵלֵךְ בְּגֵיא צַלְמָוֶת לֹא־אִירָא רָע כִּי־אַתָּה עִמָּדִי שִׁבְטְךָ וּמִשְׁעַנְתֶּךָ הֵמָּה יְנַֽחֲמֻֽנִי׃

Psalm 23:4 (Masoretic text and King James Version)

**גַּם** = gam = yea (1 syllable in Hebrew)
**כִּֽי**־ = kî = though (1 syllable in Hebrew)
**אֵלֵךְ** (or **יָלַךְ**) = yālaḵ = I walk (2 syllables in Hebrew)
**בְּגֵיא** (or without prefix **גַּיְא**) = gay = through the valley (1 syllable in Hebrew without prefix **כִּ**)
**צַלְמָוֶת** = ṣalmāveṯ = of the shadow (3 syllables in Hebrew)
**אִירָא** (without prefix **יָרֵא**) = yārē' = I will fear (1 syllable in Hebrew if second vowel is not pronounced--silent vowel in Hebrew)
**לֹא** = lō = no (1 syllable in Hebrew)
**רָע** = raʿ= evil (1 syllable in Hebrew)

With this reckoning, eleven syllables is correct.

**Sources**

Davidson, Benjamin. *The Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*. Hendrickson Publishers, 1981.

Dotan, Aron. *Biblia Hebraica Leningradensia.* Hendrickson Publishers, 2001.

*The Holy Bible*, Authorized King James Version, Thomas Nelson, 1972.

Comment: Thanks for that breakdown. What threw me were the two words without the prefix ('through the valley,' 'I will fear') which I counted as two syllables each.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: Hi David. Again, thanks for getting back to me. In reviewing your entry, I guess I'm still a little stymied over why the prefixes would be dropped in 'through [ב] (the valley)' and 'I will fear [א].' I think I understand the second 'א' as being silent in the verb 'to fear' but I'm wondering if it's a pronunciation consideration in the Hebrew by dropping the prefixes thus bringing the total syllables to eleven. Again, thanks for your patience!

Comment: Hi Ed. The Hebrew letter in question [ב] attached to the Hebrew word is a prefix and serves as a preposition (in/or through (and the article 'the' is assumed)) for the root word גַּיְא.  I personally would pronounce this preposition and include it in a syllable count. To keep things simple, I gave Alter the benefit of the doubt and assumed he did not count it intentionally (for some reason) and arrived at 11 syllables for the line instead of 12. Otherwise, you can argue he was mistaken--this is what is puzzling you--you CAN in fact argue he made an error.

Comment: This seems like a stretch. Why would prefixes not count? Isn’t the whole point of the claim that the Hebrew is more poetic because it has fewer syllables? The prefixes are read and pronounced, so they definitely contribute to the poeticness or lack thereof. And if Alter indeed intended to reach a different calculation by dropping certain syllables, wouldn’t we expect him to say that at least? Also, the א in אלך is technically a prefix as well, so why not discount that?